# How to detect if PS4 doing playback using php?

Tags: php, api, rest, playstation

How to detect if PS4 is doing playback or running a game or so with php or js. Is there a REST Api or something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible because there is no open API. You can try to log in with your account into the webpage of the Playstation Network and scrape the content - but that is nothing like a REST API.